# How to set html attributes such as class using MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, class, razor

How to set html attributes using when Razor?

In the below code, I'd like to set the class attribute of  element if "Succeeded" property of the current model is true.

```
<tbody>
                @foreach (CharlieTestRunViewModel charlieTestRunViewModel in Model)
    {
                    <tr class="@if(!@charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded){'trFailedTestRun'}">
                        <td>
                            @charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded
                        </td>
                                    </tr>
    }
            </tbody>
```

But it doesn't work.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using the conditional operator:

```
<tr class="@(!charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded ? "trFailedTestRun" : "")">
```

With if:

```
<tr class="@if(!@charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded){<text>trFailedTestRun</text>}">
```

Comment: +1 But note it's the *conditional* operator.  That's my preferred one anyway, expressive.  But others will no doubt prefer an HtmlHelper extension.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Good catch! I didn't know that I'm using the operator's name wrong :)

Comment: Well I'd like to say that I've never done it - but I would be lying.  It doesn't help that it's the *only* ternary operator!

Answer (score 3):

I find using [razor helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) most elegant

```
@helper ClassIf(bool condition, string className)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      @className
   }    
}
```

and use it like

```
 <tr class="@MyHelpers.ClassIf(charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded, "trFailedTestRun")">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Extension method to HtmlHelper like this

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetFailedClass(this HtmlHelper html, bool condition)
    {
        if(!condition)
           return MvcHtmlString.Create("trFailedTestRun")
    }
```

And then in view

```
<tr class="@Html.GetFailedClass(charlieTestRunViewModel.Succeeded)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

< tr class="@(Model.Succeeded ? "trPassedTestRun":"trFailedTestRun")" >

you have to refer you model on top of your View like below

@model charlieTestRunViewModel